# How to have borders for only columns in Bootstrap table and not for rows?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

What I have tried so far is added `th` and `tfoot`. After that I tried to apply border right and left for only td, If I try to apply border top and bottom for table, border is not being applied for table bottom. And also the border thickness or colour is being different when compared to 1st and last column

Below is the code snippet which I have tried

```css
.table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table thead th {
  border-top: 1px solid #000!important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000!important;
  border-left: 1px solid #000!important;
  border-right: 1px solid #000!important;
}

.table td {
  border-left: 1px solid #000!important;
  border-right: 1px solid #000!important;
  border-top: none!important;
}

tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F8F8F8
}

tfoot>tr:nth-child(odd),
thead {
  background: #E3ECFC
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <table class="table  table-borderless ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>name2</td>
          <td>xyz</td>
          <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>name2</td>
          <td>xyz</td>
          <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>name2</td>
          <td>xyz</td>
          <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>name2</td>
          <td>xyz</td>
          <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Expected output

[image: Expected Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added `tfoot>tr:last-of-typ`e and `thead>tr:first-of-type`

```css
tfoot>tr:nth-child(odd),
thead {
  background: #E3ECFC
}

tr>td,
tr>th {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

thead>tr:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

tfoot>tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  height:150px /* change here */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">4</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">5</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How to increase height of last row, I was about to edit the question too?

Comment: I have just edited the code if this helpful mark as accepted @vamsisai

Comment: Works for me, Is there any possibility to have rounded corners for the table as shown in the image?

Comment: let me try the code